# Is there any online tool for converting coordinates between different EPSG?

Tags: coordinate-system

Every time I want to do conversion, I need to get into the console to run proj.4. Is there any online tools for converting coordinates between different EPSG?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This one's pretty handy: http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/

Also useful for batch conversions.

Comment: this tool is really more handy~! How about including Z-axis conversion?

Comment: Awesome! Just in case the original URL's forwarding breaks, the tool is currently at https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/

Answer (score 5):

To do a one-off projection, I usually use the geometry service on our ArcGIS Server's REST endpoint.

You could also use ArcGIS Online's Rest Endpoint, which is available [here](http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project).

Here is [a sample](http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/project?inSR=4326&outSR=3857&geometries=%7B%0D%0A%22geometryType%22%20%3a%20%22esriGeometryPoint%22,%0D%0A%22geometries%22%20%3a%20%5B%0D%0A%20%7B%22x%22%20%3a%2075,%20%22y%22%20%3a%2019%7D,%0D%0A%20%7B%22x%22%20%3a%2080,%20%22y%22%20%3a%2030%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%7D&f=HTML) which shows how you can project from 4326 to 3857.

Please note that you need to comply with their Terms & Conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Two other handy tools for future reference:

- [twcc.fr](http://twcc.fr) (the world woordinate converter)
- [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/map#srs=32631&x=481874.748385&y=5487432.617363&z=6&reproject=1&layer=streets), very useful for both transformation, retrieving available  coordinate systems, ...

And to find which coordinate system might be suitable for your needs : [georepository.com](http://georepository.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried, GDAL, .net package with nuget, doesn't work,

I have tried, above http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu/, it does not give correct result.

I have tried, ArcGIS Online's Rest Endpoint, which is available here. it works fine.

Now, introduce you the best solution is 
[proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js)

It is very easy to use, in client browser, just see example,

```
proj4.defs([
[
'EPSG:4326',
'+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees'],
[
'EPSG:2230',
'+title=NAD83 (2230) +proj=lcc +lat_1=33.88333333333333 +lat_2=32.78333333333333 +lat_0=32.16666666666666 +lon_0=-116.25 +x_0=2000000.0001016 +y_0=500000.0001016001 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs'
]
]);

proj4('EPSG:2230','EPSG:4326',[6053765.97863,2201827.64981]);
```